# CSS Box, vertical divider

Tags: css

For a year ago, I was totally green in coding CSS, but thanks to mostly this site, I managed to get a good understanding, espoecially in the jsfiddle examples you often show the solution in.
I have been searching the net for a solution.
I cannot seem to put a divider between 2 div's
I have a layout as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/9cgm7nsv/

```css
* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {color: rgb(48, 48, 48); background: rgb(170, 170, 170); margin: 1px 0px 0px; }
a {color: rgb(70, 122, 167); font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; background-color: inherit;}
a img { border: none; }

p { padding: 1px 3px; }
h1 { background-color: rgb(58, 82, 127); color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding: 3px 10px; }
h2 { background-color: rgb(58, 82, 127); color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding: 5px 10px; }
h3 { background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10); color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding: 3px 10px; }
h4 { background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding: 3px 10px; }
table {border-collapse:collapse; margin: 0px; color: black; width: 100%;}
table, td, th {border:1px solid black; font-size: 11px; padding: 2px 5px 2px;}
th {background-color: rgb(120, 120, 120); color: rgb(230, 230, 230);}
button {padding: 3px;}

#container { width: 1202px; margin: 3px auto;padding: 1px; text-align: left; border:black; background: rgb(184, 184, 184);}

#navigation { height: 2.2em; line-height: 2.2em; width: 1200px; border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); background: rgb(75, 75, 75);}
#navigation li { float: left; list-style-type: none; border-right: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); white-space: nowrap; }
#navigation li a { display: block; padding: 0px 10px; font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: inherit; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }

#col-container {
 display: table; 
 width: 1200px; 
 border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); 
 margin: 1px 0px; 
 background:#FFF;
}

#col {
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 1px;
 width: 60%; 
 vertical-align: top; 
 background:blue; 
 color:#222; 
 border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#colside { 
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 1px; 
 width: 20%; 
 vertical-align: top; 
 background:blue; 
 color:#222; 
 border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200); 
}

#splitcontentleft {
 float:left; 
 width:50%;
}

#splitcontentright {
 float:right; 
 width:50%;
}

#imgbutton {padding: 0px;}

#footer {
 clear: both; 
 width: 1200px; 
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 8px 0px; 
 border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); 
 font-size: 0.9em; 
 color: rgb(240, 240, 240); 
 background: rgb(50, 50, 50); 
}

#footer p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; }

div.box {
 margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px; 
 border: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192); 
 background-color: rgb(250, 251, 252); 
 color: rgb(80, 80, 80); 
 line-height: 1.3em; 
}

div.vertical-line{
      width: 10px;
      background-color: white;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
    }

div.horisontal-line{
      width: 100%; /* Line width */
      background-color: white; /* Line color */
      border-top: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
      height: 3px;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global2.css" title="global" media="screen,projection" />
 <title>Local page</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">
  <script src="nav2.js"></script>

  <div id="col-container">

    <div id="colside">
      <div class="box">
     <h4>Left side</h4>
     <p>Test text</p>
     <p>Test text</p>
    </div>
     </div>

   <div class="vertical-line"></div> <!-- Divider between left side and middle -->

    <div id="col">
     <div class="box">
     <h4>Center</h4>
     <p>Test text</p>
     <p>Test text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="horisontal-line"></div> <!-- Divider between upper and lower part of middle -->

    <div id="splitcontentleft">
     <div class="box">
      <h4>Lower left</h4>
      <p>Test text</p>
      <p>Test text</p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="vertical-line"></div> <!-- DOESN'T work. Divider between lower left and lower right -->

    <div id="splitcontentright">
     <div class="box">
      <h4>Lower right</h4>
      <p>Test text</p>
      <p>Test text</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="vertical-line"></div> <!-- Divider BETWEEN middle and right side -->

    <div id="colside">
     <div class="box">
     <h4>Right side</h4>
     <p>Test text</p>
     <p>Test text</p>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div> <!-- col-container end -->

  <script src="footer2.js"></script>
 </div> <!-- Container end -->

</body>
</html>
```

Problem is between lower left and lower right section of the page.
I litterally tried everything, however there must be a solution I haven't tried, I hope.
I have tried from time to time over a year, still without any luck.
Most of the page works perfect, just not the divider between the 2 sections.
Any advice or info is much appriciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The biggest issue is that you have declared `#col-container { display: table; ...` without any correlating HTML `<table>` code. So, do you want to use `display: table;`, or `display: grid;`? [Mozilla CSS table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :)
I am not sure, what you mean, do you mean that I should use TR or TD instead of H4 and P, or DIV?<br>
I followed your link, but got a bit confused.

Comment: I did explore and research more into grid layout, and it seems to be able to help me. I have always overlooked it, but maybe I shoudn't.
It should be possible to make the following: grid-template-columns: 200px 1px 400px 1px 400px 1px 200px;

Comment: I entered another problem, Internet Explorer doesn't support grid?
There's an auto prefixer, but when coding, I like to have 1 language, not coding in one, and converting to IE.
Am I overlooking something? Totally new to grid, and only medium at CSS. And it seem like a worse solution to what I had, that only had a problem in the vertical line. Can someone help me getting started if theres a solution to Internet Explorer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now I"m confused. You have table elements in your CSS code  Can you show me the HTML table code so I can help you find the error?

Comment: I'm just trying to assess how to answer the question. How much explanation is needed? Basic? Intermediate? Advanced?

Comment: I haven't changed anything yet, so it's still as it's shown in OP. I just read up on grid, and tried examples from the internet. Those didn't work in IE, however i also read it can be converted to be compatible with IE. I am not good at CSS but have some understanding. Like Padding sometimes doesn't work, that is not something I knew, and don't know when it's not possible. So very basic, to beginner. Grid is something i know absolutely nothing about, exept what I have read.

Comment: I have read following pages: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp , https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ , https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-css-grid-and-the-new-autoprefixer/ , https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/WJgpzX (doesn't work in IE, shows 4 rows) And thank you very much for staying here and help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed 2 things in the CSS, making the `width:100%;` in both `id`'s:

```
#splitcontentleft {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

#splitcontentright {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
}
```

The rest of my changes are in the HTML. The decision was to stay with `display:table;` so that the page would render correctly in IE as well as other browsers. To do that, you must have an HTML Table. The basic table format is:

```
<table> <!-- opens the table -->
  <tr> <!-- the first row in your table -->
    <td> <!-- your first table cell/column inside the row -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table> <!-- everything has to close -->
```

When I looked at the format of your grid/table, I counted 5 columns and 3 rows. First, I changed the `<div id="col-container...` to `<table id="col-container...` to identify a table layout:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
  <script src="nav2.js"></script>
  <table id="col-container">
```

I added a `<tr>` to mark the first row, and I changed the `<div` to `<td`. Notice that I left your style `id="colside"` and added `rowspan="3"`. You need to indicate the rowspan so that you don't end up with 2 empty `<td>`'s with each row (your right side `<div>` is a repeat of this).

```
<tr>
    <td id="colside" rowspan="3">
        <div class="box">
            <h4>Left side</h4>
            <p>Test text</p>
            <p>Test text</p>
        </div>
    </td>
```

The next part is your `vertical-line`, again changing it from `<div>` to `<td` and adding the `rowspan="3"`.

```
<td class="vertical-line" rowspan="3"></td> <!-- Divider between left side and middle -->
```

Then we change your "Center" block. This area changes a little bit because the top part is only on the first row. But... if you look at what is underneath it, it needs to stretch across 3 columns. So we change that to:

```
    <td id="col" colspan="3"> <!-- center wrapper -->
        <div class="box">
            <h4>Center</h4>
            <p>Test text</p>
            <p>Test text</p>
        </div>
    </td> <!-- close center wrapper -->
```

We haven't left the code for the top 5 columns yet. We need to repeat what we did on the left side and add another vertical line. And then we close the table row with `</tr>`.

```
    <td class="vertical-line" rowspan="3"></td> <!-- Divider BETWEEN middle and right side -->

    <td id="colside" rowspan="3">
        <div class="box">
            <h4>Right side</h4>
            <p>Test text</p>
            <p>Test text</p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This next part is the horizontal line that you are using to seperate the "Center Section" from the Left and Right underneath it. This represents the second row of your table.

```
<tr>
    <td class="horisontal-line" colspan="3"></td> <!-- Divider between upper and lower part of middle -->
</tr>
```

The next section is the third row and falls under that horizontal-line. This was the part that was causing a problem in your display. The line looks a little thick to me, definately over 10px, but that might be a browser issue. Still, it works.

```
<tr>
    <td id="splitcontentleft">
        <div class="box">
            <h4>Lower left</h4>
            <p>Test text</p>
            <p>Test text</p>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td class="vertical-line"></td> <!-- DOESN'T work. Divider between lower left and lower right -->

    <td id="splitcontentright">
        <div class="box">
            <h4>Lower right</h4>
            <p>Test text</p>
            <p>Test text</p>
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Lastly, you close your `</table>`

```
</table> <!-- col-container end -->

        <script src="footer2.js"></script>
    </div> <!-- Container end -->
```

And here is the result of all these changes. I would love this exercise to have helped you understand coding a little better. If you have any questions, please let me know.

```css
* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; word-wrap: break-word; font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {color: rgb(48, 48, 48); background: rgb(170, 170, 170); margin: 1px 0px 0px; }
a {color: rgb(70, 122, 167); font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; background-color: inherit;}
a img { border: none; }

p { padding: 1px 3px; }
h1 { background-color: rgb(58, 82, 127); color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding: 3px 10px; }
h2 { background-color: rgb(58, 82, 127); color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding: 5px 10px; }
h3 { background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10); color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding: 3px 10px; }
h4 { background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); color: rgb(204, 204, 204); margin: 0px; padding: 3px 10px; }
table {border-collapse:collapse; margin: 0px; color: black; width: 100%;}
table, td, th {border:1px solid black; font-size: 11px; padding: 2px 5px 2px;}
th {background-color: rgb(120, 120, 120); color: rgb(230, 230, 230);}
button {padding: 3px;}

#container { width: 1202px; margin: 3px auto;padding: 1px; text-align: left; border:black; background: rgb(184, 184, 184);}

#navigation { height: 2.2em; line-height: 2.2em; width: 1200px; border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); background: rgb(75, 75, 75);}
#navigation li { float: left; list-style-type: none; border-right: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); white-space: nowrap; }
#navigation li a { display: block; padding: 0px 10px; font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: inherit; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); }

#col-container {
    display: table;
    width: 1200px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 1px 0px;
    background:#FFF;
}

#col {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 60%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background:blue;
    color:#222;
    border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#colside {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background:blue;
    color:#222;
    border: 1px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
}

#splitcontentleft {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

#splitcontentright {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
}

#imgbutton {padding: 0px;}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 0.9em;
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

#footer p { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; }

div.box {
    margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192);
    background-color: rgb(250, 251, 252);
    color: rgb(80, 80, 80);
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

div.vertical-line{
      width: 10px;
      background-color: white;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
    }

div.horisontal-line{
      width: 100%; /* Line width */
      background-color: white; /* Line color */
      border-top: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 100);
      height: 3px;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <script src="nav2.js"></script>

<table id="col-container">
    <tr>
        <td id="colside" rowspan="3">
            <div class="box">
                <h4>Left side</h4>
                <p>Test text</p>
                <p>Test text</p>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="vertical-line" rowspan="3"></td> <!-- Divider between left side and middle -->

        <td id="col" colspan="3"> <!-- center wrapper -->
            <div class="box">
                <h4>Center</h4>
                <p>Test text</p>
                <p>Test text</p>
            </div>
        </td> <!-- close center wrapper -->

        <td class="vertical-line" rowspan="3"></td> <!-- Divider BETWEEN middle and right side -->

        <td id="colside" rowspan="3">
            <div class="box">
                <h4>Right side</h4>
                <p>Test text</p>
                <p>Test text</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="horisontal-line" colspan="3"></td> <!-- Divider between upper and lower part of middle -->
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="splitcontentleft">
            <div class="box">
                <h4>Lower left</h4>
                <p>Test text</p>
                <p>Test text</p>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td class="vertical-line"></td> <!-- DOESN'T work. Divider between lower left and lower right -->

        <td id="splitcontentright">
            <div class="box">
                <h4>Lower right</h4>
                <p>Test text</p>
                <p>Test text</p>
             </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> <!-- col-container end -->

        <script src="footer2.js"></script>
    </div> <!-- Container end -->

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much elbrant. Now seeing your work and well put info along the code, makes me better understand it. So yes, it have helped me a great deal to understand the code. Especially with the colspan and rowspan. You have saved me countless hours of trying. When I look at the code and your comment, it all makes sense, but I can surely say, I woudn't have found that out myself anytime soon.

Comment: Now, instead of just copy/paste, I'll use your post as reference, I think I'll remember this better when I actually write the code myself, altho it is based on your code. You have explained it very well, and I am not in doubt as I read it. It's too late now to correct my code, but will do it tomorrow. Thank you so much elbrant, i'll get back to you if I enter something I don't understand or are in any doubt about. You sir, have saved me alot of problems. The 10px will be 1px, it was made, to see clearly when I edited my code, thought the vertical divider vas behind.Thank you so much elbrant :)

Comment: I cannot give you reputation, as i'm below 15 points: 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.' But you deserve alot imo.